# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'

Tags: python, machine-learning, serialization, pickle, xgboost

I'm a beginner of Data Analytics. I'm trying to import a pickled file into python but I can't solve this problem. Here's my code:

```
import pickle

with open("xgb_tuning_train_data.pkl", "rb") as fr:
    data = pickle.load(fr)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d0e5155fc161> in <module>()
      2 
      3 with open("xgb_tuning_train_data.pkl", "rb") as fr:
----> 4     data = pickle.load(fr)

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

Comment: is it allowed to share the .pkl file? then, we can analyze how it is pickled... because, your code seems to be OK! as snakecharmerb said, there must be something with the pkl file

Comment: which python version are you using? could you try "python -m pickletools xgb_tuning_train_data.pkl"

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was occurring because I was saving the model using `joblib` and loading it using `pickle`. Loading the same model in `joblib` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

That means your file containing only empty values or space or tab like that.
so you should recreate that file with some value. after you will be able to read that file.

Comment: hi i have not any pickled file in my codes.but vscode shows same error: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.